# Upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8 using Technet?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade, microsoft-technet

I want to go get a TechNet subscription to test some Windows software before I buy it.

I want to replicate upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8 with specific software in a virtual machine then see how stable or if possible to do it at all. I looked at the list of software but they only show Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise.

Do you know if there is an Windows 7 to 8 Upgrade ISO available for Technet Standard or Pro?

Comment: What does it say on their site?

Comment: I do not know- I cannot find anything- also chat is only for subscribers so i cant ask them quickly. It just says for testing only... but I want to know if i can test the upgrade procedure?

Comment: The Windows 8 iso on TechNet is both Windows 8 Core and Windows 8 Pro depending on the license you use.  You do understand there is only a single ISO that exists right, and what product you actually install, is based on the license provided right?

Comment: Thanks Ramhound - I did not know that. I got the technet subscription in the end and doing tests now. I used the keys provided under "my keys"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this myself previously - the Windows 8 Pro media (which is the same on Technet as MSDN) can be used to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro.

Running Setup from the CD (or .iso image if you are using a program to mount it) within Windows 7 allows you to perform the in-place upgrade.

Comment: Cool thanks a million. Faster reply than technet them selves.. :)